# highlighting cell differences in excel

Tags: excel

I need help with an excel issue.
I have two worksheets, sheet1 and sheet2. Data on sheet1 looks like the following:

```
User ID   department
US1234    Dept1
US1345    Dept1
US13556   Dept2
US13557   Dept3
```

While Sheet2 loks like the following

```
User      department
US00987   Dept4
US1345    Dept6
US88567   Dept5
US1234    Dept1
US13556   Dept3
US45789   Dept6
US13557   Dept3
```

I want to highlight on Sheet2 those rows which, for the given ID, have a different department than the one indicated on Sheet1. To be more clear, I need to know which users have a different department on sheet1 than on sheet2, and I only care about the ones that are on both sheets.

For instance, on this example, the highlighted rows on Sheet2 would be:

```
US1345  Dept6
US13556 Dept3
```

Any tips on how to do this will be very welcomed.

Thank you very much and kind regards

Comment: Do you strictly need to highlight the cell or so long you are able to find out which cells matches your criteria would be fine?

Comment: It would be fine to detect which cells match the criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula on `Sheet2` in `C2`

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$5,MATCH(Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$5,0)),B2)<>B2`

or in Excel 365 as spill down formula

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$5,MATCH(Sheet2!A2:A8,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$5,0)),B2:B8)<>B2:B8`

It returns true if the departments are different, false if they are equal.